# Update defaultValue on React component after successful request

Tags: javascript, reactjs, state

I've got a DropDown component (built in a separate component library) which renders a bunch of options.
The dropdown component which I am consuming already supports an array of objects as its source AND i can set the default value quite easily if the list is static - i.e if it does not come from an API.
However, when the  options are retrieved via an API call in the consumer application and set via `setState` I cannot seem to get my default to work.

My goal is to display the regular order of the options if there is no default or display the default if there is one available.

Below is the useEffect hook which aims to do that:

```
useEffect(() => {
    axios
      .get(endpoint)
      .then(response => {
        setDropdownOptions(newObj);
      })
      .then(() => {
        setDefault(relationshipInitialValue);
      })
      .catch(error => {
        // Error handling here
      });
  }, []);
```

`relationshipInitialValue` comes from the props of the component.

What seems to happen however is that the default never gets set and the first option is set as the default. 
I am fairly convinced that this is a sync issue but do not know how to proceed. Any help appreciated.
Previous posts seem to focus on class-based components absent of hooks, hence the question.

Answer (score 0):

You need to rerender the dropdown after setting default value in state. You can create a unique key for that dropdown and update that key whenever you want to  do like post ajax call.

```js
const [key, setKey] = useState(Date.now());
const [defaultValue, setDefaultValue] = useState('');

useEffect(() => {
 // ajax call
 // update default Value
}, []);

useEffect(() => {
 // update key to rerender Dropdown
 setKey(Date.now());
}, [defaultValue]);


<Dropdown key={key} defaultValue={defaultValue} options={options} />
```

Answer (score 0):

Some time ago I used the default value for the dropdown library for async requests and had similar problems as you. I tried different approaches but in the end, I stopped using the defaultValue and took full control of the dropdown using just currentValue or value depending on the library. It requires slightly more code but you have full control of the dropdown and it's easier to catch bugs with such implementation.

Here's a sample implementation:

```
const [selectedValue, setSelectedValue] = useState({
    label: "Option 1",
    value: "option1",
});


return (
    <AsyncSelect
        getData={getData}
        onSelectChange={setSelectedValue}
        value={selectedValue}
    />
)
```